# Opening .scmp file in Visual Studio 2015 opens as XML and not as comparison UI

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, database-comparison

I'm opening a Database Schema Comparison (.scmp) file and the file opens in Visual Studio as XML. However, the need is for the file to open in the Server Data Tools tab.

I have tried opening from Visual Studio and Windows Explorer.

Using Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly me. I didn't notice that SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) had been corrupted and wasn't showing as installed. Installing SSDT solved the issue.

Comment: Didn't solved for me.  I did use Visual Studio Installer and added the Data tools there in VS 2019 16.8.6 and since we can use the Tools / SQL Server / New Schema compare from there we can see the UI but double clicking the .scmp just load the configuration file

Answer (score -2):

The .scmp file is a XML file essentially. It is stored in the Schema Comparison folder of the project system by default.  When you double click the .scmp file in the Visual Studio, the Select Source/ Target Schema page appears, on which shows the comparison settings and options that you have set. When you click the OK button on that page, SchemaCompare1.scmp file (for example) shows in the edit explorer.

However, you may not open a .scmp file by double-clicking it on the disk. It may be because the .scmp file is used to save comparison settings and options between usage sessions (any combination of a project, database, and .dbschema file), it associates with a solution so you can open it by double-clicking it in the Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for the education on what a .scmp file is. But that does not tell me why double-clicking in Visual Studio opens as XML when it should open the UI.